# Delete Windows user created by IIS ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-10, applicationpoolidentity

I was having problems booting into my user profile in Windows 10 and was able to fix this by setting RefCount to 0 for my user profile in this registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-xxx`

I have several ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core websites hosted in IIS (version 10 and not IIS Express) and I realized in `C:\Users` these websites have associated Windows users created for them.

Correct me if I'm wrong I believe these "Windows users" were created by the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` when each website was created.

The problem is that these "Windows users" also have the registry RefCount set to 0 so I think that's why I wasn't able to boot into my profile.

Now I want to delete these "Windows users" but when I delete the website and application pool in `inetmgr` these "Windows users" still exist in `C:\Users`.

The question is how can I delete them the proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

You are correct, starting from IIS 7, it creates new profile for each application pool, this can be disabled in "Advanced settings" / "Load User Profile".

The easiest and safest way to delete unused user profiles with their folder on drive with helps Microsoft control panel "User profiles":

- Right click on "Computer", and select "Properties", then click on
  "Advanced system settings" (alternative way - just run "sysdm.cpl").
- Go to tab "Advanced" and click button "Setting" in "User profiles" group.
- Unused profiles that created by IIS pool will have name "Account Unknown", select it and click "Delete" button.

[image: User profiles window]

Profiles, which have references, cannot be deleted, them will have disabled "Delete" button.
Some reasons why profile is locked:

- IIS application pool, which uses this profile, still exists.
- SQL Server has "Logins" related to this profile (SQL management studio
  / Security / Logins).

After remove all references to profile need to reboot machine.